# Is it decidable to know the number of positions used by a Turing machine for a fixed input?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, computability, undecidability

I'm having trouble proving if the following language is recursive, recursively enumerable, or not r.e. at all: the set of all encodings of Turing machines $M$ such that the number of positions in the tape used by $M$ when the input is 0011 is less than 10.

I'm suspicious the problem is unrecognizable but I can't come up with any reduction to prove it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can run $M$ on $0011$ until it either loops or uses more than $10$ positions.

Comment: Hint, the above comment tells you the way to show the problem is decidable.

Comment: @JohnL. I have to know what happens if M loops forever. If I "bound" the number of steps looping within the same 10 positions, it is guaranteed that, if M loops forever, it will do it without visiting more than those positions. But I can't find a pattern.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus but M might loop and use less than 10 positions.

Comment: If it uses more than 10 positions, you can immediately stop. Otherwise, either it halts at some point, or it loops at some point (we even have an a priori bound on when that must happen, though this is not necessary).